# Getting substring of a token in for loop?

Tags: string, batch-file, for-loop, token

I have this `for` loop to get a list of directory names:

```
for /d %%g in (%windir%\Assembly\gac_msil\*policy*A.D*) do (
echo %%g
)
```

Output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Assembly\gac_msil\policy.5.0.A.D
C:\WINDOWS\Assembly\gac_msil\policy.5.0.A.D.O
C:\WINDOWS\Assembly\gac_msil\policy.5.20.A.D.O
C:\WINDOWS\Assembly\gac_msil\policy.5.25.A.D.O
C:\WINDOWS\Assembly\gac_msil\policy.5.35.A.D.O
C:\WINDOWS\Assembly\gac_msil\policy.5.55.A.D.O
C:\WINDOWS\Assembly\gac_msil\policy.5.60.A.D.O
C:\WINDOWS\Assembly\gac_msil\policy.5.70.A.D.O
C:\WINDOWS\Assembly\gac_msil\policy.6.0.A.D.O
```

I want to get the folder names starting with "policy" but `echo %%g:~29` doesn't work.
I also tried to `set x=%%g` and then `echo %x:~29%` and still doesn't work.

So, how do I get substring from token in `for` loop?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Of course that `set x=%%g` and a substring extraction of x should work, but be aware that if the substring is taken *inside a FOR loop*, it must be done with ! instead of % (Delayed Expansion):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%g in (%windir%\Assembly\gac_msil\*policy*A.D*) do (
set x=%%g
echo !x:~29!
)
```

Comment: useful tips here, thanks. Helped me write a script which I didn't think was possible.

Comment: @Aacini Is it possible to extract a substring directly from the parameter `%%g`, without using an auxiliary variable `x` and without enabling DelayedExpansion?

Comment: @AlfredoCapobianchi: Short answer: No. Long answer: if you carefully read the question, you should note this phrase: _"`echo %%g:~29` doesn't work"_.

Comment: You saved my day also! 
The usage of setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion along "!" is what works inside a for loop

Answer (score 9):

On the other hand, if you want to know "How to get the last part (name and extension) of a token in for loop", the answer is: use the ~Name and ~eXtension modifiers in %%g replaceable parameter:

```
for /d %%g in (%windir%\Assembly\gac_msil\*policy*A.D*) do (
echo %%~NXg
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure that'll come in handy someday.

Comment: Can you expand on how this actually works? I wanna do the same thing but I want all filenames (not just "policy" ones). I tried `*` and `\*.*` but it breaks on spaces and gives unexpected results.

Comment: @RayCheng Wow, searched/experimented for a good hour or so regarding how to substring iterate-variables in a for loop. And then you show up and go all "oh and btw here is how you do it using 2 magic letters". This was exactly what i was looking for, thanks for saving my day :)

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a similar question, and I wanted to compile here the 3 working solutions:

1. Use `EnableDelayedExpansion` in your batch file, as in the accepted answer

   ```
   @echo off
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   for /d %%g in (%windir%\Assembly\gac_msil\*) do (
    set x=%%g
    echo !x:~29!
   )
   ```
2. Use `for /f` to process the output of a `dir` command

   ```
   for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('dir /ad /b %windir%\Assembly\gac_msil\*') do @echo %%g
   ```
3. And finally, the **optimal solution** in this case, using enhanced variable substitution. See the end of the help at `for /?` for more information on this syntax.

   ```
   for /d %%g in (%windir%\Assembly\gac_msil\*) do @echo %%~nxg
   ```

Answer (score 1):

A simple

```
dir /B %windir%\Assembly\gac_msil\*policy*A.D*
```

should do the trick. If you want to loop over it:

```
for /f %%g in ('dir /B %windir%\Assembly\gac_msil\*policy*A.D*') do (
    echo %%g
)
```

Comment: Neat! I'll use your suggestion but marked Aacini's as answer since that solution made me learn more.

Comment: Can you expand on how this actually works? I wanna do the same thing but I want all filenames (not just "policy" ones). I tried `*` and `\*.*` but it breaks on spaces and gives unexpected results.

Comment: @laggingreflex: So you want `dir /B %windir%\Assembly\gac_msil\ ` - that should list all files in that directory?